# Pelican image links break when viewing article through "categories"

Tags: python, pelican

I am sure I'm missing something obvious. I'm defining Categories through folder names inside the content folder. If I click `content` while viewing a page, I see folder names (e.g. categ1, categ2) plus 'misc', that's fine. When I click categ1, I see one complete article but the image links are now all broken.

```
localhost:8000/category/categ1.html
```

What I would like to see is just a click-able list of articles in that category. Or at the very least, not broken links.

(I have similar behavior if I try to use tags, but one thing at a time...)

There are no category lines in the `.rst` files.

Besides name, timezone etc. I am using these in my configuration.

UPDATE: Images are in the Images folder in Content. I've also put a copy of Images folder in categ1, but no help.

```
THEME = 'nmnlist' 

PATH = 'content'

# ARTICLE_PATHS = ['articles']    # have tried this also

STATIC_PATHS = ['images', 'pdfs']

RELATIVE_URLS = True  # have tried False also

PLUGINS = ["render_math"]
```

Comment: how are the images being inserted into your category page (i.e., is it automatically done by the theme or are they inserted in Markdown)? what do the urls of the broken images look like? what should unbroken image urls look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like this might be a problem with image URLs being relative.

**The Problem**

If this is the case, suppose you have a Markdown page in `content/mypage.md` that is generated into `localhost:8000/mypage.html`, and it has a (working) reference to an image:

```
![Alt text](content/myimage.png)
```

which is rendered into the html:

```
<img src="content/myimage.png" />
```

and points to `localhost:8000/content/myimage.png`. However, if you then try and process that same Markdown into HTML for a categories page, it will render the same image markdown:

```
![Alt text](content/myimage.png)
```

into the same html:

```
<img src="content/myimage.png" />
```

but since this is on the categories page at `localhost:8000/categories/mycategory.html`, this relative image URL now points to `localhost:8000/categories/content/myimage.png` and the image is broken on categories and tags pages.

**The Solution**

The solution is simple: one `/`. Use absolute references to images in your Markdown by prefixing them with a `/`: instead of using `content/myimage.png`, use `/content/myimage.png`:

```
![Alt text](/content/myimage.png)
```

That will always render the image at `localhost:8000/content/myimage.png`, regardless of what page it is on.

Comment: Ok! Thanks @charlesreid1 - adding the leading slash fixes the display of the images. Thanks also for the explanation. I am still not sure how this works exactly, (the purpose and best use of the `static_paths`, `article_paths`, and `relative_urls` parameters in pelicanconf.py) but you've given me some clues, and I can experiment.

Answer (score 1):

The  `content`-folder is the input-side. After applying the `pelican pelicanconfig.py`-command the output-side is generated in the   `output`-folder. I think that any pathes for rendering has to fit the output-side at the end. I use a  `content/images`-folder and this is copied by the  `pelican pelicanconfig.py`-command  completely to the  `output/images`-folder.

I had to modify the proposed solution. Using my structure of the folders, it works for me when I set in the md-file:

```
![png5](../images/image5.png)
```

With `..` we get from the post-folder a level higher to the output-folder and from there to the images-folder.

**Appendum :**
I have elaborated a different solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083594/how-to-add-image-from-within-content-subfolder-pelican/46122542#46122542) that works from **Pelican 3.5** on and later.