# How to add image from within 'content' subfolder - pelican

Tags: pelican

I got a structure

```
content/
├── applications
│   └── 2017
│       └── 08
│           └── 30
│               ├── article.md
│               └── forecast1.png
```

I want the img files to be same directories as the `md`  files so that they can be put to:

```
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = 'posts/{date:%Y}/{date:%b}/{date:%d}/{slug}/index.html'
```

I have `STATIC_PATHS = ['static_files','content']` however, the

```
[alt]({attach}applications/2017/08/30/forecast1.png)
```

gives error:

```
WARNING: Unable to find `applications/2017/08/30/forecast1.png`, skipping url replacement.
```

How can I include  image into my `md` file in this simple case?

**EDIT**
so I changed the config `applications` is my category to:

```
PATH = 'content'
STATIC_PATHS = ['static_files','applications/2017/08/30/img', 'applications/2017/09/01/img']
ARTICLE_PATHS = ['applications', 'cat2', 'cat3']
```

I also added the `!` before the `[alt]()` and still the images are not copied over to output.

**EDIT2**
iT WORKS WHEN APPLY EDIT ABOVE AND CHANGE `({attach}img/forecast1.png)`

Comment: I'm aiming to do something similar as you do, but I've not tryied yet... Pherhaps you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794909/pelican-image-links-break-when-viewing-article-through-categories?rq=1) some explanations or ideas.

Comment: @pyano can you upvote then so more people can see? And adding `/content` does not help when i run `make devserver` The image file is not showing in the `output` directory.

Comment: Why do you want the images to be in the same directories as the articles? That's not clear.

Comment: @jonrsharpe becouse I want order in my files. I want to know which images belong to which html file. Very important.

Comment: ...to you. But regardless, that's not really something Pelican's set up for; per [the docs](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.7.1/content.html#linking-to-static-files) any directory with static files must be in `STATIC_PATHS`, so you'll have to add every new article's image directory.

Comment: It is not logical at all. I believe this is bad design practice and should be rethink. Putting all images in one huge directory regardless of their origin is messy. Its ok if you do it in WYSIWYG where its done automatically but not in static site...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me (following [this](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/content.html#attaching-static-files)):

```
content/
├── p001
│   └── myArticle001.md
│   └── img001
│       └── myPic1.png
│       └── myPic2.png
├── p002
│   └── myArticle002.md
│   └── img002
│       └── myPic1.png
│       └── myPic2.png
```

In `pelicanconfig.py` set:

```
PATH = 'content'
STATIC_PATHS = ['p001','p002']
ARTICLE_PATHS = STATIC_PATHS
```

In the `md`-files set:

```
![pic_A1]({attach}img001/myPic1.png)
![pic_A2]({attach}img001/myPic2.png)
```

and

```
![pic_B1]({attach}img002/myPic1.png)
![pic_B2]({attach}img002/myPic2.png)
```

**Probabley** you missed a **!** only at the begin of the command. So you might try this:

```
![alt]({attach}applications/2017/08/30/forecast1.png)
```

Or try this:

```
PATH = 'content'
STATIC_PATHS = ['applications']
ARTICLE_PATHS = STATIC_PATHS
...
![alt]({attach}2017/08/30/forecast1.png)
```

Comment: I have edited the original post above according to your suggestion but still no luck.

Comment: btw what is the purpose of the `!` ?

Comment: @mCs: The **!** is just according the pelican-docs for `md`-files: `![Icon]({attach}icons/icon.png)`. If my examples has helped you, would you mind to use the green *accetped answer*-button (so more people can see )? Thank you.